# c++ base class and derived class constraints

Tags: c++

The following question might look like a duplicate but I couldn't find the exact idea anywhere else in the site.

A brief introduction: This question raised as I was trying to understand a little more complexity inheritance combination in my class.

One note before I present the question - I don't look for a sort of "Solution", only wish to discuss with you about the topic and acquire a better thinking.

Suppose you have the following lines:

```
class C : public B 
{
    public : 
        C (const B& b) : B (b) {}
        B& operator*() {return *this;}
};

int main() {
    A* pA = new B();
    C& c = pA -> doIt();
    *c = *pA;
    c = *pA;
    return 1;
}
```

This code isn't full and this is the whole purpose - assume it does complie and extract the constraints in this code.
Still I wouldn't just write a code and ask you to explain any constraint of the top off your head but instead I will add my concreate question:

What constraints do we have for the following line :

```
C& c = pA -> doIt();
```

As far as I understand, the above code has one staring constraint which is the hierarchy order of these class : C is derived of B and B is dervied of A (correct me If I'm wrong..)

I was trying to actually define these classes while keeping the hierarchy I described above, and I couldn't have doIt() to return a type of its derived class C. I can use incomplete type C& in the prototype of an A function but yet I cannot return an object of type C.

Thank you in advance,
SyndicatorBBB

Comment: As it stands, `A` must be a (possibly indirect) base of `B`; `A` must define a member function `C & doIt()`, and `C` must define an assignment operator that accepts an `A`.

Comment: How can you implement the mmember function C & doIt() for A? You must create in the body of this function a complete type of dervied class and It isn't possible.

Comment: you mean a member function of c return the object of class A ?

Comment: No, I understand that A must have a function which its return type is C or C&. No matter what you choose this function must create a complete type object of C in order to return it - which is not possible because C is dervied class of A.

Comment: In general base classes shouldn't know about the classes that derive from them, apart from a few cases (which I reccomend to rethink your design). in order to allocate object C in class A you the compiler must know what C is defined to be. Therefore pA->doIt must be defined in a source file with the header file that the C class is within included and more than likely the object will be dynamically allocated, or allocated with the static keyword.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Is it possible that c = *pA; would work with no operator casting, operator =, or constructor?

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB: You have to have *one* of those, I suppose. You could try giving `A` a conversion operator to `C`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Yes that what I was thinking - I have to have one of those. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class C;

struct A
{
    C & doIt();
};

struct B : A
{
  void operator=(A const &) { }
};

class C : public B
{
public :
    using B::operator=;
    C (const B & b) : B(b) {}
    B & operator*() { return *this; }
};

C & A::doIt()
{
    static B bimpl;
    static C cimpl(bimpl);
    return cimpl;
}
```

Note that the implicit assignment operator hides the base version, so we need explicit unhiding of the operator with the `using` declaration.